# Python-Mysql insert query

Tags: python, null, sql-insert, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to insert values into MYSQL database using python code, but struggling to fix the error, though the error code sounds familiar.

My Query is as follows

**query="insert into Case_history (Patient_id ,  Patient_name ,  Gender ,  Dob ,  Address ,  Phone_no ,  Occupation ,  Date_entered) values (%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"**

**cur.execute(query, (3, 'myname', 'Male', '2000-12-11', None, '123', '', '2020-11-12 19:49:21'))**

****Programming Error:**** 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' at line 1

Patient_id is an integer as per table definition. Also the table has a row number column which is set to autoincrement, so I excluded the row number from the query.

I followed the post from [here](http://python.zirael.org/e-mysql7.html) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/resolve-usage-of-quotes-error-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your-mysql-server-version-for-the-right-syntax-to-use#:%7E:text=for%20your%20parents%3F-,Resolve%20usage%20of%20quotes%20ERROR%201064%20(42000)%3A%20You%20have,the%20right%20syntax%20to%20use%3F&text=In%20MySQL%2C%20you%20can%20use,single%20quotes%20or%20double%20quotes.), but unable to find the root cause. What I understood is that I can send Null values from Python to MYSQL using ****None**** keyword, but its not working. If I modify the query as below then it works but this does not insert ****NULL**** into the table.

****query= "insert into Case_history (Patient_id ,  Patient_name ,  Gender ,  Dob ,  Address ,  Phone_no ,  Occupation ,  Date_entered) values (3, 'myname', 'Male', '2000-12-11', '', '123', '', '2020-11-12 19:49:21'))****

****cur.execute(query)****

I am using ****Python 3.7****. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I didn't find a way to solve this and so I decided to give a space in my table instead of NULL. It will cost some space for now and in the future if the table grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to insert the records without the %S options.

**Insert into table_name values (string of tuple values) **

Also changed the datatype of the columns in the table as varchar.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `%s` as the placeholder for *all* data types in your Python script/MySQL table, not only for string literals:

```py
query = """INSERT INTO Case_history (Patient_id, Patient_name, Gender, Dob, Address,
                                     Phone_no, Occupation, Date_entered)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
vals = (3, 'myname', 'Male', '2000-12-11', None, '123', '', '2020-11-12 19:49:21')
cur.execute(query, vals)
```

Comment: Tim, I tried that too and still it failed at the same position of the query.